# Print every year in a loop with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, loops, date-range

My source documents contain two values (years) that define a range. I put them in variables `$year1` and `$year2`. I now need to print to output a -Element for every year in between these two values, including start and end-year. I see a way in creating a loop with recursion, but esp. don't see how to increment the value by one every time. Any ideas?

Comment: It is useful to know that a recursive solution *can*  work for millions of items and be efficient (time and space O(N)) at that.

Answer (score 3):

The Piez method isn't applicable when the size of the sequence that must be generated isn't known in advance and isn't limited.

In such case an XSLT solution *must* use recursion.

**Here is a generic "iterate" template that performs an action on an initial input and then on its result, until a given condition is specified**.

This transformation is *tail-recursive* and works without stack overflow with an intelligent XSLT processor:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:action>
   <end>1000000</end>
 </my:action>

 <xsl:variable name="vAction"
      select="document('')/*/my:action"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="iterate">
   <xsl:with-param name="pAction" select="$vAction"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pInput" select="0"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="iterate">
   <xsl:param name="pAction"/>
   <xsl:param name="pInput"/>

   <xsl:if test="string-length($pInput)">
       <xsl:variable name="vResult">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$pAction">
           <xsl:with-param name="pInput" select="$pInput"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
       </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:copy-of select="$vResult"/>

       <xsl:call-template name="iterate">
         <xsl:with-param name="pAction"
              select="$pAction"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pInput" select="$vResult"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="my:action">
  <xsl:param name="pInput" select="0"/>

  <xsl:if test="not($pInput >= end)">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat($pInput+1,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), an intelligent XSLT processor that optimizes tail recursion into iteration produces the wanted result without stack overflow. This is the case with Saxon 6.5.4, which I used to produce the result.

**The problem is that not all XSLT processors recognize and optimize tail-recursion.**

**For such processors, one can use DVC - style recursion**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
    <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="1000000"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="displayNumbers">
  <xsl:param name="pStart"/>
  <xsl:param name="pEnd"/>

  <xsl:if test="not($pStart > $pEnd)">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$pStart = $pEnd">
      <xsl:value-of select="$pStart"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="vMid" select=
       "floor(($pStart + $pEnd) div 2)"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
       <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$pStart"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="$vMid"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
       <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$vMid+1"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="$pEnd"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**this transformation produces the correct result without any crash using MSXML4.**

With this DVC transformation the maximum recursion-depth is only Log2(N) -- in this case 19.

**I would recommend using the [FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)**. It provides DVC variants of commonly used higher-order functions, such as `foldl()` and `map()` making it possible to produce the DVC variant of almost any recursive algorithm.

**Of course, in XSLT2.0 one would simply write**:

```
<xsl:sequence select="1 to 1000000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

## XSLT 1.0 Solution

Refer to the [Piez technique](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9945e300).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="year1" select="2010" />
<xsl:variable name="year2" select="2013" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="(//node()|//@*)[position() &lt; ($year2 - $year1 + 2)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($year1+position()-1,'&#x0A;')" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## XSLT 2.0 Solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="year1" select="2010" />
<xsl:variable name="year2" select="2013" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="$year1 to $year2" separator="&#x0A;" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output

Both these style-sheets will yield product...

```
2010
2011
2012
2013
```

Comment: Sean, the Piez method is only applicable for a sequence with a known-limit of length. Which maynot be the current case. What if the number of items to be generated is thousands? See my answer for two variants of a recursive solution that works OK and efficiently even for millions of items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help

I am working with xslt 2.0, so Dimitris last short note has done the trick:

```
<xsl:template name="yearranges">
   <xsl:param name="year1" />
   <xsl:param name="year2" />
   <xsl:for-each select="$year1 to $year2">
      <year>
         <xsl:sequence select="."  />
      </year>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I have to print every year in a -tag. That was simple. Trickier was, that the year has to be formatted as xs:integer for xsl:sequence which is done in the call-template:

```
<xsl:call-template name="yearranges">
   <xsl:with-param name="year1" as="xs:integer" select="xs:integer($year1)" />
   <xsl:with-param name="year2" as="xs:integer" select="xs:integer($year2)" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Thanks again
Oliver